# How to set autocomplete="off" globally?

Tags: asp-classic, autocomplete

How to set to

> autocomplete="off"

all the input type element on my website globally? For example, i want to declare it on my global.asa? Is it possible to do this? I am using Classic ASP.

Comment: global.asa is serverside. has nothin to do with html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set autocomplete attribute of form To off like this:

```
 <form autocomplete="off">
  ...
 </form>
```

Comment: I already tried that but what I am looking for is it sets globally not on the pages. Because If i have around 75 pages with forms, i need to add an autocomplete attributes one by one. For example, i set the autocomplete off attibute on my global.asa

Comment: using jquery could do the trick. but you still have to include the jquery script in all your pages...